# Columns alias required while creating view - why?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

today, when i was creating view I've came across one of the silliest error in oracle. Getting to the point, I tried to execute this simple query:

```
CREATE VIEW dept_agg AS 
SELECT department_id, MIN(salary), MAX(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id;
```

but i got error saying:

> ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias
>   00998. 00000 -  "must name this expression with a column alias"

Can anyone explain me why columns alias are so needed by Oracle in above query? Especially that alias aren't needed when I'm not creating view and just running the select statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably curious, if you run this, it works

```
SELECT department_id, MIN(salary), MAX(salary)
FROM employees
```

But as part of the view, this is an issue. This is because your query window, whatever it is, simply displays what you entered for the field. This is like, dynamic name, not stored into DB. But to store the definition, oracle has the rule

> Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($), and pound sign (#)

Hence you need to provide legal aliases for your dynamic columns. And how to do it is explained by @Gordon... in his answer

Comment: @J.Doe See this https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a view and the view needs names for columns, just like a table does.  This is usually done using aliases:

```
CREATE VIEW dept_agg AS    
    SELECT department_id, MIN(salary) as min_salary, MAX(salary) as max_salary
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY department_id;
```

You can also include the names as part of the view itself:

```
CREATE VIEW dept_agg(department_id, min_salary, max_salary) AS    
    SELECT department_id, MIN(salary), MAX(salary)
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY department_id;
```

Comment: My point was that I couldn't understand why default column names, that would come from the select wasn't enough for the view and it's columns names, like - Department_id, Min(salary), Max(salary)?

Comment: But thanks anyway, because you show me how it should be done, what's more in two ways

Comment: @J.Doe . . . Think of the default column names as something added for the final presentation to the user, rather than something the database actually knows about.